# Meaning of 'Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler'

Tags: meaning, phrases

Wish to understand the meaning of Einstein's words:

> Make everything as simple as possible, but not simpler.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this precisely because I'd have to ask Einstein and my crystal ball is broken.

Comment: I'd conjecture that he meant something along the lines of reduce your equations or theories to their most simple form e.g. E=M/c2 without losing any of their precision.

Comment: Don't overcomplicate your thinking, but don't "under-complicate" it at the expense of being incorrect.

Comment: Cut out all the dead wood, but don't throw out the baby with the bath water.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, oversimplify means to dumb down, i.e., to reduce the importance or effectiveness of something. As a language trainer, this quote is my mantra: communicate your message in an easy and quick way avoiding complicated sentence structures which lead to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

It means that one should find the simplest way of explaining or expressing something, that's just short of *oversimplifying*.

There.  I hope I have managed to follow his dictum.

Comment: But can we really 'oversimplify'? I feel that there is only one correct and simple explanation. Anything other than that is away from the most simple answer (or in other words - it is complex). That is what I thought he meant by making things simple and not simpler. 'Simpler' is actually complex.

Comment: People used to oversimplify physics by assuming that it followed [Newton's laws of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion) for about 2 centuries before Einstein came in with his [work on relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity). The Newtonian laws were correct in the sense they worked well with the constraints that were imposed by the lack of precise equipment and limited speeds on Earth.

Comment: I think one could say that they were an *oversimplification* of the true laws of nature that were captured more precisely by Einstein's work, which was essentially a simlification of the universal laws without the former *oversimplification*.

Comment: @vovick - Your third comment sounds good.  Yes, it is possible to oversimplify almost anything!

Answer (score 1):

I think he was saying two things:

1. Make sure your statements are true (science).
2. Find the simplest human language to describe the thing completely.

If 0 is complicated, 10 is the simplest description, 11 might be the step you are removing information/adding false information to make it "simpler", thereby departing from the underlying truth of what you are trying to describe (and moving from science to fiction).

I think he is saying "10 is as simple as possible, but to go to step 11 you need to make the underlying thing simpler (and in the process factually incorrect)".

Answer (score 1):

If I dare link this to Einstein's “If you can't explain it to a six year old, you don't understand it yourself”, then the context for *simple* is communication and *simpler* means it misses the accuracy of the message.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant of [Occam’s Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

If you cannot understand it in English, perhaps the Latin will help you:

> Entia non sunt multiplicanda, praeter necessitatem

Answer (score 0):

Started as a comment but would not fit the last 10 chars;

Though it can provide some insight it is more of a Buddhist koan than advice or a dictum. It looks just silly if you apply it to anything else; You should make as much money as you need but no more. You must walk as far as you should but no further. It is like the phrase "Form follows function" [Wright]. It is obvious to engineers but since it flows trippingly from the tongue it sounds like genius to anyone else.  I'm Very! pro-Einstein but this quote gets a bit more play than I would expect. What he failed to say was "Always have a picture to use for your theories." Had he one in the end he might have got further on the unified field theory.

It is useful to remember that once he was found studying a sharp pencil. When asked why he said, "So simple!" There is the lesson I think.

Answer (score -1):

When you are trying to explain or making a report you should be as simple as it possible, that anybody can understand, but people who are reading, listening or watching your report, talk or presentation shouldn't have idea that's that simple and you made little effort, so not simpler. They should understand that your report, talk or presentation is important and that's not that simple you worked hard to do that report, and they can understand easily."Try to be as simple as it possible, but not simpler"